# How did can I find important partions of any android devices?

Tags: adb, fastboot

Please Help Me !!!

How did can I find important partions of any android device . Using adb or fastboot . Such as, boot, recovery, etc...

I mean to backup any androdi device rom . I have tried with "ls /dev/block/" . Then I see many things.

[image: That is the output of "ls /dev/block/"]
        I've tried another with "cat /proc/mounts" . This one give me more pressures .
Take a look at this .

[image: Pressures :P]

Sorry for my English :'(

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27238/16575) or, even better, at [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575), which most likely gives you the necessary details.

Using that information, your best approach to backup via ADB might be:

```
# find the device for the partition
mount | grep system
# from the output of the above (data from your screenshot), now back it up
# using "dd":
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 of=/mnt/sdcard2/system.img bs=1M
```

`if` is the device to back up, `of` the target (I just placed the image file in the root of your sdcard, you might wish to adjust that). **Take care not to mix up the two, or you might destroy your system!** (this is why `dd` sometimes is backronymed "data destroyer"). `bs` defines how much data to read/write in a single operation, my example uses 1 MB; you might play with this and e.g. use "8M" to speed things up, but do not set this too high.

Above example just handles the `/system` partition. Repeat it similarly for any of the other ones listed in the linked question which you want to have backed up.

Comment: This error occurs. Why ? 
Please !


C:\Windows\System32>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
su
shell@android:/ # mount | grep system
mount | grep system
sh: grep: not found
127|shell@android:/ #

Comment: Maybe because there's no `grep` found in `$PATH`? You could try `busybox grep` instead (if busybox is found). Or simply skip the `grep` part and check the output manually: this part is only needed once to find out where the devices are. Once you got them, they won't change, so you can save your `dd` statements for subsequent use.