# In TWRP Wipe button, the description in the slider say "factory reset" but its other description doesn't seem so. Which one is correct?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, factory-reset, dalvik, dalvik-cache

When I access to the TWRP (version 3.2.1-0) and select the Wipe button, the screen says:

> Wipes Data, Cache, and Dalvik (not including internal storage)
>
> Most of the time this is the only wipe that you need

But the description of the slider says:

> Swipe to Factory Reset

Is Factory Reset the same with Data, Cache, and Dalvik wiping? What is the difference between the data it is about to wipe and internal storage?

Comment: "internal storage" is the different name for the "sdcard section" `/sdcard`. This is the one you can access via MTP.

Comment: The data that can be accessed via MTP is more than just data in SD cards, am I right?

Comment: You will get a better understanding on reading TWRP FAQ [What should I wipe in TWRP?](http://twrp.me/faq/whattowipe.html), though it's not updated with the latest developments.

Comment: 1) via MTP only */sdcard* and */external_sd* is accessable. 2) while your question is about the difference between "normal" wipe and "advanced" wipe (formatting), it is anyway interesting question if TWRP is even able to perform "real" factory reset at all

Comment: @alecxs why is the folder is named as `/sdcard` when it's not actually an sd card? And why do you think TWRP cannot perform real factory reset?

Comment: 1) you can find even such philosophical debates here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137081 2) recently figured out that "real" factory reset will send instructions to Keymaster discard encryption keys stored in TEE https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56532243#56532243

Comment: very good explanation of android partitions on xda-developers

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215683/trying-to-understand-the-options-in-twrp-backup#comment276228_215683

Comment: although it's deleted question you may find it helpful https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lyaQYDN7wkIJ:https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231411/why-do-people-consider-mobiles-inbuilt-memory-as-internal-storage-and-sd-cards