# `Wipe Cache` option missing in Google Pixel 2! (A/B device)

Tags: recovery-mode, cache, google-pixel-2, ab-partition

I am not finding the option **`Wipe Cache`** in the recovery mode of **Google Pixel 2**.

can anyone tell how could i enable it if it is disabled by default and is it there in this device or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device doesn't have `/cache` partition

**Reasons**

- `/Cache` partition is not required to be as big  on devices which have A/B partition catering to [seamless updates](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/) since it doesn't need to store OTA updates which are done seamlessly

> The cache partition is no longer used to store OTA update packages, so there is no need to ensure that the cache partition is large enough for future updates

- As further explained in [Implementing A/B updates](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement)

> A/B devices do not need a recovery partition or cache partition because Android no longer uses these partitions.
>
> For non-A/B updates, the cache partition was used to store downloaded OTA packages and to stash blocks temporarily while applying updates. There was never a good way to size the cache partition: how large it needed to be depended on what updates you wanted to apply. The worst case would be a cache partition as large as the system image.

Pixel 2 like my device MiA1 follow this system and they probably decided to do away with the entire partition instead of keeping it small

- `/Cache` is also used by Google Play downloads as explained here [What is the /cache partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27232). I am *assuming* that is handled by `/data/cache`

**Edit:** Thanks to BoLawson, who pointed out that app cache is on B partition. See [APK Caching|AOSP](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/apk-caching). Note that this is only applicable for popular apps / apps on the device out of the box.

Comment: Adding to that, if you install a custom recovery like TWRP on such devices that use the A/B paritioning schema, the `Wipe Cache` button actually does nothing at all, due to the absence of `/cache`.

Comment: So how does one wipe cache on those devices without root – considering this is sometimes a good advice when some things start misbehaving, e.g. due to broken files in cache?

Comment: @izzy No way I know of... You can't wipe

Comment: @beeshyams If you refer to my comment from "15:31", I don't get it. Maybe it's because I didn't follow the link? No, that doesn't describe how to "wipe cache" :)

Comment: @Izzy : I was drawing your attention to the fact that it can't be cleaned as stated earlier but yes edit being an interesting tidbit thought of tagging you. Sorry for the delayed response, Saw only now