# Install TWRP to only one slot or offline boot.img file, not both

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, ab-partition

I want to install TWRP on my phone that uses the A/B partition schema. The official TWRP installer ZIP by default installs to both `boot_a` and `boot_b`. This always breaks the system in the inactive slot because I install Magisk after flashing/OTA.

Can I install TWRP to only one slot, or an offline `boot.img` file (like Magisk Manager supports)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this way, I ended up creating a script on my own.

Lucky enough, installing TWRP to `boot.img` isn't hard at all. The install script in TWRP just replaces `ramdisk.cpio` with the one `ramdisk-twrp.cpio` provided in the ZIP.

The effective part of the script is as following, root is of course required.

```
ln -s /system/bin/linker64 /sbin/linker
cp <path-to-magiskboot> /sbin/magiskboot
mkdir /data/local/tmp/twrp
cd /data/local/tmp/twrp
/sbin/magiskboot --unpack <path-to-boot.img>
cat <path-to-[ramdisk-twrp.cpio]> > ramdisk.cpio
/sbin/magiskboot --repack boot.img
cp new-boot.img /sdcard/new-boot.img
```

Now the TWRP-installed `new-boot.img` is located at `/sdcard/`.

To install to a single slot, `dd` the boot image out and apply the same process as shown above and `dd` the new image back.