# Install recovery ramdisk vs flash current TWRP: the difference?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp

I want to know the proper way of installing TWRP because recently I spent quite a lot of time bricking/unbricking my phones after flashing the ROMs, so I don't want spend it again. While learning the TWRP features I figured out two different ways of installing the TWRP:

[image]

So far I found many [useful articles](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-twrp/) explaining ramdisk way of TWRP installation
also quite a lot of beautiful questions/answers posted here on Android SE
[Install TWRP to only one slot or offline boot.img file, not both](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201481/install-twrp-to-only-one-slot-or-offline-boot-img-file-not-both/201506#201506)
[Why can't I write to recovery using fastboot on A/B device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209673/why-cant-i-write-to-recovery-using-fastboot-on-a-b-device/209692#209692)
[Can't flash custom TWRP recovery image on Motorola Moto G7 Power phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/211996/cant-flash-custom-twrp-recovery-image-on-motorola-moto-g7-power-phone/212005#212005)

Having read all that, I have a general understanding that newer A/B devices have no separate recovery partition where TWRP can be installed, so instead recovery is put onto the `boot` partition in some `ramdisk` section, this is how I understood the subject. Practically that means that one need to have recovery `.zip` or `.img` file in hand, and *push* that file onto the device to be able to install it on ramdisk.
As opposed, with `Flash current TWRP` we don't need any files, we just make the currently booted TWRP persistent, and bootable on next and subsequent boots.

The question is: **are those two options have equivalent result?**

My understanding is that "Flash the current TWRP" is simpler as it does not require any file copy. So why we have them both in TWRP menu?
Am I missing something?

Comment: the option should throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

early recovery in ramdisk arrangements required the zip installer, because the other option was not available in the TWRP menu. the result is the same, installers are provided for historical reason.