# How do I install OTA updates while rooted with Magisk?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, ota-update, 9.0-pie, systemless-root

First of all, here are my specs (let me know if I'm missing anything):

- Device: Moto G7 (river)
- OS: Android 9
- Build Number: PPOS29.114-134-2
- Magisk Version: 20.0
- Magisk Manager Version: 7.5.3

I installed Magisk through TWRP.  The device is fully rooted.  I want to install the latest OTA update, and I've been trying to do it using [this guide](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-ota-update-rooted-android-device-guide/).  I'm stuck on step 2:

> tap on the UNINSTALL button and select the RESTORE IMAGES option.

When I follow these instructions, I get this error:

> Stock backup does not exist!

**How can I install the update and stay rooted?**

*Notes:*

- *I am okay with re-rooting if necessary.*
- *For some reason, I can't boot into TWRP using the custom recovery I know I installed.  I just get the opened up maintenance android.*
- *This is NOT a duplicate of [How do I update an OTA while retaining TWRP and Magisk, only with my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200410/how-do-i-update-an-ota-while-retaining-twrp-and-magisk-only-with-my-phone)*

Comment: You cannot apply OTA updates unless you are completely stock... period. You will need to flash the stock image that matches what you currently have, or the latest stock image in it's entirety. This will completely wipe the device. That said, Moto has really gotten lazy about releasing firmware images and are often many months behind which is a problem because you cannot downgrade a Moto device. I would honestly suggest going to the XDA forums for your specific device and asking there as this will likely require some finesse that is outside the scope of this Q&A format.

Comment: BTW, that isn't an off the cuff comment to push you away or make light of your question... I wrote the "restore to stock" guides on XDA for most Moto devices on XDA from 2015-2018 so I have some background in what I am talking about here.

Comment: try out flashfire